# Select option transparent

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to remove white background in select option text. Creating custom class and adding background-color: red, works...background-color: transparent does not work.

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <span class="nav-link">
      <select class="form-control language">
         <option class="custom-color">SI</option>
         <option class="custom-color">EN</option>
      </select>
   </span>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: See the comments over at the linked duplicate question, it's not possible to make the options transparent using a default select element. You'd have to build your own.

Comment: Perhaps it is not the element that has the background, but a parent somewhere up the tree. Hence why red works, red covers the parent background while transparent just exposes it.